# How to reference another component from my code part

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

i have a button that opens a modal, this one works.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@loginDialog.ShowLogInDialog">
     Login
</button>
<LoginDialog @ref="@loginDialog" />
```

But because i want to do 2 different things on my click, i want to do this from a method instead.
But somehow this does not work, what do i do wrong?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">
     Login
</button>
<LoginDialog @ref="@loginDialog" />
```

Code

```
public LoginDialogVM loginDialog;

        public void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            loginDialog.ShowLogInDialog();
            loginDialog.dialogIsOpen = true;    // tried both as this is what actually happens in the loginDialog        
        }
```

Comment: `But somehow this does not work` what happens? Any Errors? What doesn't work?

Comment: Nothing happens, the function fires. Without errors. So somehow its not the same way of refering to my 'loginDialog'